# What is the Origin for Meatwad, Master Shake, and Frylock?

Tags: aqua-teen-hunger-force

In the intro to *Aqua Teen Hunger Force* we sometimes see a mad professor with them, but I can't remember who actually creates them, how, or why.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Dr. Weird](http://aqua-teen-hunger-force.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Weird) created them. Their origin is explained in the movie, [*Aqua Teen Hunger Force Colon Movie Film for Theaters*](http://aqua-teen-hunger-force.wikia.com/wiki/Aqua_Teen_Hunger_Force_Colon_Movie_Film_for_Theaters):

> Meanwhile, Frylock begins to tell the origin story of the Aqua Teens: they were created by Dr. Weird, along with a chicken nugget who had gone by the name of Chicken Bittle. In the flashback, Dr. Weird proclaims that the Aqua Teens were created for one purpose, and one purpose only: to crash a jet into a brick wall. Realizing the pointlessness of this mission, Frylock simply diverted the jet (after a struggle with Bittle) and set a course to Africa, where they would try to use their intelligence to solve world hunger. While parachuting down to the earth, Bittle was attacked and eaten by a lion. The remaining three then tried to help a small village, but the natives feared them to be monsters and ran away. After realizing they couldn't be much help, they hopped back in the jet and rented out a house in New Jersey. Shake and Meatwad state that they cannot remember any of this, but Frylock explains it was because they were too busy playing their Game Boys and talking about Level 3 to pay any attention, and Shake says he at least clearly remembers Level 3.

[Walter Melon](http://aqua-teen-hunger-force.wikia.com/wiki/Walter_Melon) has claimed that he created both Dr. Weird and the ATHF members, but "it was confirmed in 2010 during "Aqua Teen Hunger Force Live" by series creator Dave Willis that Dr. Weird was indeed the creator of the Aqua Teens."